# Bootstrap 4 set elements in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to set links in one line on bottom, like "Link 1 left bottom", "Link 2 center bottom", "Link 3 right bottom" but "Link 2" not centered on PC and mobile devices.

HTML:

```
            <div>
                <a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
                <a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
                <a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact{
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#api{
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#link{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
}
```

How it looks now

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use bootstraps build in classes `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` to achieve that easily.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
  <a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
  <a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all of the css code and use `d-flex` and `justify-content-*` for the container.

> Use justify-content utilities on flexbox containers to change the alignment of flex items on the main axis (the x-axis to start, y-axis if flex-direction: column). Choose from start (browser default), end, center, between, or around. - [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
  <a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
  <a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap 4 you can do by this way.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<ul class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> for more : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/

Answer (score 1):

Use **d-flex**  http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

1. **flex-md-row**  : for displaying inline for medium and large devices

[image]
 2. **flex-column** : for displaying in column in mobile devices

[image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-md-row flex-column justify-content-between text-center">
  <a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
  <a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
  <a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
}
#contact{
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#api{
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#link {
    padding-top: 0.17em;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
    <a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
    <a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code:**
*This make div in bottom:*(like you said:`left bottom`...)

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

```css
div{
text-align: center; 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact{
   float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#api{
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0.17em;
}

#link{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a id="contact" href="/contact">Link 1</a>
<a id="link" href="/repo">Link 2</a>
<a id="api" href="/json">Link 3</a>
 </div>
```